amici __init__.py syntax error ../../amici/init.py
I am following the instructions to install solverstudy from here:
https://github.com/ICB-DCM/solverstudy/tree/master
I send the command to install from the requirements.txt document, but I get the following error:
src\amici\python\sdist\amici\__init__.py", line 1
          ../../amici/__init__.py
          ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

I am using python 3.8.20 as the instructions state. I must be doing something wrong since no one else is having this trouble, but I cannot figure out what it is.

What do you mean by "send the command to install from the requirements.txt document"? What command did you type?

I followed the directions in https://github.com/ICB-DCM/solverstudy/tree/master and this is the command
pip install -r requirements.txt

If I try to install amici with
pip install amici
I get an error
  amici\src\cblas.cpp(16): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cblas.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

